# illuminaHumanv2.db returning NA for all Illumina probe ID to gene symbol conversion

Tags: r, bioconductor, microarray, illumina, geoquery

***This question has been cross-posted on [Biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/9561427/) but has not received any answers yet, so I'm posting it here. I'll update here if it gets answered there.***

I have downloaded a miRNA expression dataset from NCBI GEO `(GSE25631)` to study differential gene expression and perform other analyses. As mentioned in GEO, this profiling was performed on GPL8179 Illumina Human v2 MicroRNA expression beadchip. Accordingly, I installed the `illuminaHumanv2.db` package to annotate the Illumina probe IDs. However, when I tried to convert the Illumina probe IDs to their corresponding gene symbols, it returned `NA` for all the probes. Can anybody identify the issue with this approach? Here's the R script which I used.

```
library(GEOquery)
library(limma)
library(illuminaHumanv2.db)

Sys.setenv(VROOM_CONNECTION_SIZE = 256000)

data <- getGEO(GEO = "GSE25631", 
           destdir = "E:\\GSE25631",
           GSEMatrix = TRUE,
           AnnotGPL = FALSE,
           getGPL = FALSE,
           parseCharacteristics = TRUE)

data <- data$GSE25631_series_matrix.txt.gz

raw_intensity <- exprs(data)

samples <- as.character(pData(data)[,"title"])

raw_intensity_log <- log2(raw_intensity)
colnames(raw_intensity_log) <- c(rep("GBM", 82), rep("Normal", 5))

probe_id <- rownames(raw_intensity_log)
mapping <- data.frame(Gene = unlist(mget(x = probe_id, envir = illuminaHumanv2SYMBOL, ifnotfound = NA)))



head(mapping, 10)
               Gene
ILMN_3166935   NA
ILMN_3166938   NA 
ILMN_3166940   NA
ILMN_3166941   NA 
ILMN_3166943   NA
ILMN_3166944   NA
ILMN_3166945   NA
ILMN_3166948   NA
ILMN_3166952   NA
ILMN_3166953   NA
```

The `GSE25631_RAW.tar` file in the supplementary section has all the Probe ID to Gene mappings but I'm curious to know why this approach didn't work.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the probe names are valid using a different tool? Could this be caused by having windows line endings in your file and those are included when querying? Or, since your `E:\\` path suggests you are using Windows, could it be the other way around and something is inserting a `\r` before every trailing `\n`?

Comment: I checked the probe-to-gene mappings present in illuminav2SYMBOL. Surprisingly, none of my probe IDs are present, so it returned NAs. The list doesn't seem to contain any mappings for miRNAs. I ended up using the mapping file provided by the manufacturer.

Comment: I closed this as non-reproducible since the issue seems to be very specific to your case and your probe names.